# DNN Manage Users Bug

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

So I'm using DNN version 07.03.02 (109).
When I go to manage users, select a user to edit and then change the username but don't update and then go to tab manage roles and select a new role DNN bugs and I get a reference not set to an instant of an object error. And then when I try to edit again the same user it says user not found. When I clear the cache I can edit the user again.
Does anyone know about this bug or is there a fix?

Comment: This really isn't a good type of question for StackOverflow, it would be better on the DNNSoftware site

Answer (score 0):

This is a recreatable bug in the system, however, this isn't something that can be resolved here.  You might submit this as a bug in the DNN Core for resolution in future versions.